# How to get the last row from a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have one table it has only one column which is `varchar`.

I want to get the last row, but I cannot apply `order by`.

the following query does not give the required result.

```
select top 1 from SampleTbl order by columnName desc
```

Comment: _"I cannot apply order by"_ Can't you? Why not? It looks to me like you did... _"the following query does not give the required result."_ Why not? What is the required result? What result did you get instead? What is an example of the data in the table, and which _"last row"_ should be returned, by what criteria of _"last"_? Please read the Help Centre to learn how to ask a good, clear question. Chances are you're trying to sort that `varchar` as if it's a number, and not liking the ASCII sort you get instead, but how would anyone know with so vague a description?

Comment: if data is "Querying,SQL,Server" . it should give Server, but its giving SQL

Comment: I'm taking varchar as datatype

Comment: There's no such thing as a "last row" because there's no ordering of rows unless you specify it with `ORDER BY`. There's nothing wrong with ORDER BY either. Post a *reproducible* example - table script, INSERT statements, SQL statement that returns what you say and an example of what you expected

Comment: @viveknuna **why** return `Server` when `SQL` is quite clearly the last value lexicographically? Why do you want the *middle* value to appear? What are your criteria?

Comment: How can you get the last row from a table with one column which is a `VARCHAR` datatype?
That's a not a very good table design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Database tables are unsorted by nature. There is no *last row* in the table.

If there is a clustered index, The records are stored in the same order as the clustered index, but that does not mean that's the order of the rows - Unless you specify an `order by` clause in your query, no database guarantees the order of the rows returned by said query.

From [Wikipedia page on tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(database)#Tables_versus_relations) (emphasis mine):

> In terms of the relational model of databases, a table can be considered a convenient representation of a relation, but the two are not strictly equivalent. For instance, an SQL table can potentially contain duplicate rows, whereas a true relation cannot contain duplicate tuples. Similarly, representation as a table implies a particular ordering to the rows and columns, whereas a relation is explicitly unordered. However, **the database system does not guarantee any ordering of the rows unless an ORDER BY clause is specified in the SELECT statement that queries the table.**

See also Aaron Betrand's [Bad habits to kick : relying on undocumented behavior](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior), the paragraph titled "Ordering without an ORDER BY":

> ... I want to make it quite clear: ordering is arbitrary unless you use an ORDER BY clause.  You should never, ever, ever rely on the ordering you observe in a query without an ORDER BY -- and you should only issue a query without an ORDER BY clause if you truly do not care what order the results come back.  In such a case, you may as well imagine that the rows are going to come back in a different, random order each time, even though that is not truly the case (random has a meaning completely separate from arbitrary, but like I said, just imagine).

Comment: Worth noting this isn't an uncommon scenario - parallel processing of results almost guarantees they'll be return in the order they become available unless ORDER BY is specified