# TSQL to choose a record that meets the criteria or first one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for company phone numbers and one of the columns is `IsPrimary` which is a `boolean` type. The table looks like this:

```
CompanyId  |  AreaCode  |  PhoneNumber | IsPrimary
123            212         555-1212      0
234            307         555-1234      1
234            307         555-4321      0
```

As you can see in the first record, even though the phone number is the only one for `CompanyId: 123`, it's not marked as the primary.

In such cases, I want my `SELECT` statement to return the first available number for that company.

My current `SELECT` statement looks like this which does NOT return a number unless it's set as the primary number.

```
SELECT *
FROM CompanyPhoneNumbers AS t
WHERE t.IsPrimary = 1
```

How can I modify this `SELECT` statement so that it includes the phone number for `CompanyId: 123`?

Comment: So you want to partition by companyid and order by isprimary desc then select the first one for each of these?

Comment: How do you define "first"? Having a first value implies an order of some kind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: Unless you have a column to use for `order by`, [There is no "first" row.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168234/how-to-get-the-last-row-from-a-table-in-sql-server/48168275#48168275)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query might be different depending on what you are actually up to.

If you already have the `CompanyId` and only need the phone number for it, that's easy:

```
select top (1) pn.*
from dbo.CompanyPhoneNumbers pn
where pn.CompanyId = @CompanyId -- A parameter provided externally, by calling code for instance
order by pn.IsPrimary desc;
```

However, if you need all companies' data, including one of their phones (for example, you might be going to create a view for this), then you need a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*, oa.*
from dbo.Companies c
  outer apply (
    select top (1) pn.*
    from dbo.CompanyPhoneNumbers pn
    where pn.CompanyId = c.Id
    order by pn.IsPrimary desc
    ) oa;
```

I have deliberately used `outer` instead of `cross` apply, otherwise it will filter out companies with no phone numbers listed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using an apply statement. This looks at the exact same table and returns the record with the highest `IsPrimary` so, this would return the records with a 1 in that column. If there are more than one marked as primary or not as primary, then it returns the phone number, with area code, in ascending order.

```
select      b.*
from        CompanyPhoneNumbers     a
cross apply (
                select      top 1
                            *
                from        CompanyPhoneNumbers b
                where       b.CompanyId = a.CompanyId
                order by    b.IsPrimary desc
                            ,b.AreaCode
                            ,b.PhoneNumber
            )                       b
```