# Show records only if a previous record has a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trouble shooting a certain business proces and i'm able to follow the flow in a database. I've found the error message I want to look into, but only in case of a certain flow.

My problem is how to achieve that in SQL.

For example

```
Source      Statement
--------    ------------
PORT        Cannot create
APP         No active visit
GIK         OIK
APP         No active visit
```

Now I only want to have the record with statement 'No active visit', if the previous record has a Source value "GIK".

How do I achieve that in SQL? I'm working in SSMS btw.

greets,
Stoney

Comment: Define "previous record".  How are you *sorting* the records?

Comment: [Database tables are unsorted by nature. There is no *previous row*.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48168275/3094533)

Comment: *"How do I achieve that in SQL?"*  SQL tables and datasets are **orderless** by definition without using `ORDER BY` in SQL a term like  "previous record" also does not exists.. You can't not atleast not stabile results without a column which we can use to identify the correct sort is like a `IDENTITY` column..Then we know that a "previous record" is..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thx for the info. Forgot to mention my example data was already ordered by a timestamp column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(Source) over (order by ?) as prev_source
      from table t
     ) t
where Statement = 'No active visit' and prev_source = 'GIK';
```

If `lag()` will not support then you can use `apply` :

```
select t.*
from table t cross apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from table t1 
      where t1.<identity_col> < t.<identity_col>
      order by t1.<identity_col> desc
     ) t1
where t.Statement = 'No active visit' and t1.source = 'GIK';
```

`SQL` tables represent unordered sets. If you want a specific ordering in the result set, you need one ordering column. So, use column name instead of  `?` that specify your column ordering.

Comment: The OP is clearly unaware that SQL Data-set's are inherently un-ordered, and that they need at least one additional column so they can enforce the required ordering.  You may wish to expound upon that point in your answer?  *(Then I'll upvote)*

Comment: @MatBailie My example was already ordered by a timestamp colomn. Forgot to mention that. However, I was unaware SQL Data-set's are inherently un-ordered by fact. Thx for the info!

Comment: @Stoney `ORDER BY` a timestamp column still might give deterministic (random) results, i assume that timestamp isn't a unique value in your table? Ideally you should do `ORDER BY timestamp, id` where id is a `IDENTITY` column then the SQL result will be nondeterministic (fixed)

Comment: @RaymondNijland That exactly explains some of my results. Thx